# livewallpaper crash which use libgdx

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx, live-wallpaper

I write a livewallpaper  which start from an activity, the activity uses libgdx's opengl20.
When I start the activity for the first time there is no problem, but the second time the livewallpaper crashes.  Sometimes with `shader.begin()`, not everytime.
when I not start from then activity there no problem.

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".LivewallpaperSettings" 
              android:label="Livewallpaper Settings"
              android:parentActivityName="com.me.mygdxgame.MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".LiveWallpaper"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/livewallpaper" />
    </service>

</application>
```

### Start livewallpaper code

```
            Intent i = new Intent();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15)
            {
                i.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
                String pkg = LiveWallpaper.class.getPackage().getName();
                String cls = LiveWallpaper.class.getCanonicalName();
                i.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(pkg, cls));

            }
            else
            {
                i.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
            }
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

### The crash info

```
06-27 11:03:22.576: D/dalvikvm(7139): GC_CONCURRENT freed 246K, 13% free 11375K/12999K, paused 15ms+10ms, total 61ms
06-27 11:03:22.626: W/dalvikvm(7139): threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e4c300)
06-26 11:45:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(19979): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 9758
06-26 11:45:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(19979): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 11:45:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.begin(ShaderProgram.java:745)
06-26 11:45:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at com.wall.wall.MeshShaderTest.render(MeshShaderTest.java:78)
06-26 11:45:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphicsLiveWallpaper.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphicsLiveWallpaper.java:625)
06-26 11:45:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1546)
06-26 11:45:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(19979):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1247)
06-26 11:45:09.941: E/Window(1782): Lynn . finish the function even if the screen is off.
```

### The shader

I think it has no problems.

```
    vertexShader = "attribute vec4 a_Position;    \n"
                    + "attribute vec2 a_texCoords;    \n"
                    + "uniform mat4 u_mvp_matrix;\n"
                    + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;     \n"
                    + "void main()                   \n"
                    + "{                             \n"
            //      + "   gl_Position = a_Position;  \n"
                    + " gl_Position = u_mvp_matrix * a_Position;\n"
                    + "   v_texCoords = a_texCoords;  \n"
                    + "}                             \n";

// this one tells it what goes in between the points (i.e
// colour/texture)
  fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES                \n"
                      + "precision mediump float;    \n"
                      + "#endif                      \n"
                      + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;   \n"
                      + "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n"
                      + "void main()                 \n"
                      + "{                           \n"
                     // + "  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);  \n"
                      + "  gl_FragColor =  texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);   \n"
                      + "}";
    meshShader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
```

Comment: Can u please post your shader code and the code for initializing it.

So that root cause can be determined

Comment: i post it ,but i can't find any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I alter my AndroidManifest.xml by adding "android:process=":com.me.process.main"  in activity and android:process=":com.me.process.sub"  in service. 
then the activity and the service not in a process.so their memory would not lead to the problem. 
But  I still don't know how to solve the prolem in same process.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.mygdxgame"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:process=":com.me.process.main"   >
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".LiveWallpaper"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"
             android:process=":com.me.process.sub">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@xml/livewallpaper" />
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet you are storing your `MeshShaderTest` instance in a `static` field, or you're storing the `ShaderProgram` (`meshShader`?) in a `static`.  Its hard to say without more of the code, though.

When you restart the activity quickly, Android can reuse the previously initialized DalvikVM, which means `static` fields will not get re-initialized.  However, since all the OpenGL context was thrown away, any object referencing Libgdx state will have gone stale.

For more details see http://bitiotic.com/blog/2013/05/23/libgdx-and-android-application-lifecycle/

Comment: I can understand what you said, but MeshShaderTest is a ApplicationListener store in static GDX.app, so what i should do .

Comment: I think  my problem is more complex.because  the application  is a wallpaer.when the second application begin rending , the first application rending not stop. They are not straight-forward.